# log_error not working on mysql in docker

Tags: linux, mysql, docker

I use the `mysql:5.7` official docker image and setup the `general_log_file` and `logs_error` logs on mysql using custom .cnf file but here when i setup error log then getting below error:

```
$ sudo docker-compose up
db_1   | Initializing database
db_1   | Initializing database
db_1   | Initializing database
....

^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)

$ cat mysql-custom.cnf
[mysqld]
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
general_log             = 1
log_error               = /var/log/mysql/error.log  # When i put this then getting above error.
```

Here I getting error then I put the `log_error` or `slow_query_log_file`, Anyone know that why this simple thing not work on docker ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate bcoz I'm not getting you.

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in a container, you might not have the full support of the functionalities of the underlying operating system; such behaviour is by design as you want to have a more secure and restricted environment for a specific purpose.

As such, for MySQL logs, you might want to log to MYSQL DB/tables.

For version 5.x onwards (5.1, 5.2, cannot remember) SQL supports logging to MySQL DB/tables, instead of files, and comes by default with two tables already created, `mysql.general_log` and `mysql.slow_log`.

To setup their use, you do:

Adding to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
slow-query-log
general_log=1
log-output=TABLE
```

And then restart mysql.

To backup them every day, you can run in a system with access to query the database:

```
mysqldump mysql general_log  --lock-tables=0 > general_log_errors.db
mysqldump mysql slow_log  --lock-tables=0 > slow_log_errors.db
```

(You need to use lock-tables=0, otherwise you will get the error message:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1556: You can't use locks with log tables. when doing LOCK TABLES
```

)

And then run the following queries to clean the tables.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE mysql.general_log;
TRUNCATE TABLE mysql.slow_log;
```

This is the general idea. You might want to keep logs of the last few days, and as such the MySQL TRUNCATE/DELETE queries would be more elaborated.

The tables should be there by default, maybe it was scrubbed in that docker image.

As such, for v5.7, you can create them with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `general_log` (
  `event_time` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON    UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `command_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `argument` mediumblob NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `slow_log` (
  `start_time` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `query_time` time(6) NOT NULL,
  `lock_time` time(6) NOT NULL,
  `rows_sent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rows_examined` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `db` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `last_insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sql_text` mediumblob NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Slow log';
```

Further reading: [Writing Logs into Tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/writing-logs-into-tables/)

As for creating the error_file: /var/log might not even exist in your docker file. If those two logging options above are not enough, you might create a file for testing at a directory owned by the MySQL user; one of such directories where MySQL resides is usually /var/lib/mysql.

Comment: what location of logs because I've to mount volume into host.

Comment: Edited the answer. It is logging to MySQL DB tables...not files.

Comment: Is there any way to store logs in file or any other better option, here my plan is to backup logs every day.

Comment: Due to the nature of containers, I would advise tables. Added to the answer.

Comment: But error_logs table not found on mysql db, how do i get the errors logs ?

Comment: What is your MYSQL version? If anything recent, it should be there. Is that an upgrade from older versions? (please answer to BOTH questions)

Comment: I'm using `mysql:5.7` official docker image.

Comment: Added to the answer the tables, and corrected the mysdump syntax.

Comment: Thank, I getting `General query log` and `Slow query log` but here How can I get the  `Error log` and there is no table for error !

Comment: It appears there is no support for error log into tables. You may probably create it as a file, however you must create it relative to the root of the container...eg if container is /store/mysql/var/lib/mysql , you have to ignore the root, or specify only the name of the error_log file for it to be under mysql. Not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem yesterday but mine was on setting the path for error log in my.cnf. I am used to using `log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysql.err` (which works fine in other non-docker environment), but kept when used in docker, I realized that it is not accepting `.err` extension. Then I used `.log` extension and it worked fine. Although I am running the base `mariadb:10.2` docker image but it should be the same when running `mysql:5.7` image. Just fyi: although error file is a log, it is not affected by the variable `log-output=TABLE` as it cannot be viewed in a `mysql` table. I also think logging to `TABLE` creates unnecessary burden on the server and this should be avoided if possible.